# Definition of the space $\mathcal{R}_2([\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}])$

Tags: vector-spaces, fourier-series, almost-everywhere

I'm studying the Fourier series on Zorich II book. In this context he introduces the vector space $\mathcal{R}_2([\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}])$ of function that are "locally square-integrable, as proper or improper integral".
He then says that in this space we can define an inner product as:

$$\left \langle f,g \right \rangle := \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)g^*(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

My doubt is: if this is an inner product, then it must be verified that $\left \langle f,f \right \rangle =0\iff f\underbrace{=}_{\text{in }\mathcal{R}_2([\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}])}0$. So, who is the null "vector"? A vector in this context is a function, but there is not a unique function such that $\int_\mathbb{R} |f(x)|^2\mathrm{d}x = 0$ (it suffices for example that $f$ is continuous almost everywhere and is $\neq 0$ in its points of discontinuity).

If all the functions in the space $\mathcal{R}_2([\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}])$ would be continuous, then that would be the case, but this is not.

Comment: One typically quotients by the space of functions equal to 0 a.e., so that elements are actually equivalence classes of functions up to almost everywhere equivalence.

Comment: So the null vector in that space is the class of functions that are equal to the function $f(x)\equiv 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: And so the vectors in $\mathcal{R}_2([\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}])$ are the equivalence class of locally square-integrable functions that are equal almost everywhere?

Comment: Yes, those are the vectors.